# SSAS Why is there an 'unknown' member showing when there isn't one?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssas

I've created a basic test project with a dimension based on general ledger accounts. For some reason I see an "Unknown" member show up in my dimension and I don't know where it's coming from. The underlying table only has 8 records in it, and there are no "Null", "Empty", "blank", etc... records (see image below). I'm also certain there are associated records in the associated "Fact" table (this is a test and I only have basic records).

**Can anyone explain why an uknownn member shows when there is not one or where the unknown member is coming from?**

**Please note: I know I can set the "Unknown Member" property of the Dimension to "Hidden" to just make it go away, but I'm trying to understand why it's there in the first place. There are NO unknown members**.  Also, I thought I needed to leave that property as "Visible" in case there truly is an unknown.

See screen shots below (btw... VS2015 Community, SQL Server 2014)

The underlying table (only has 8 records):

[image: The underlying table]

Here's the dimension's structure (very basic/test dimension)

[image: Dimension structure]

And here is where you can see the "unknown" member.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the Unknown member is to handling errors that occur during processing.  For example, if you have a Fact table that has foreign keys pointing to your dimension that does not have the associated primary keys then those rows would land under the Unknown member.

Comment: Sreejith is talking about this kind of errors: "Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key cannot be found when processing: Table: '{table name}', Column: '{column name}', Value: '{missing value}'. The attribute is '{dimension attribute}'. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The record was skipped because the attribute key was not found."